# Why can't ssh connect to any host inside a while loop?

Tags: shell, ssh

```
theIp=""
#1
echo $theIp | while read ip; do
    ssh -tt root@$ip
    exit
done
#2
while read ip; do
    ssh root@$ip
    exit
done < <(echo $theIp)
#3
while true; do
    ssh root@$theIp
    exit
done
```

the above 3 way about connect any host in a while statement, but only the last one succeeded, why do the first two do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` was eating up your loop's input. Probably in this case your `ssh` session exits when it gets EOF from it. That's the likely reason but some input may also cause it to exit. You have to redirect its input by specifying `< /dev/null` or use `-n`:

```
ssh -n "root@$ip"
ssh "root@$ip" < /dev/null
```

That may also apply with `-tt` since somehow it's independent. Just try.

If you're using Bash or similar shell that supports `read -u`, you can also specify a differ `fd` for your file.

```
while read -u 4 ip; do
    ssh root@$ip
    exit
done 4< <(echo $theIp)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! use -n or redirect to /dev/null didn't help, but with file descriptor it works very well..